# Javascript: If([]) unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I think in every language I know

```
if(a)
```

is the same thing as

```
if(a == true)
```

Turns out in JavaScript it isn't true, because:

```
if([])
```

Seems to act as if the condition is fulfilled, but:

```
if([] == true)
```

Does the opposite thing.

I can't really find any possible explanation, especially that this problem doesn't occur with empty string for example (which is `== true`, but isn't `=== true`, same as empty array). Is this a bug in JavaScript or what?

Comment: `if(a) [...] same as [...] if(a == true)` - erm, that might just be PHP and maybe Python? It's not nearly universal to be able to convert an arbitrary value into a boolean. At any rate, [here](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) is how truthy/falsey values work in JS.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, there is a concept of truthy and falsey values. `if` statements test the truthiness or falsiness of a given value rather than strict equality to `true` or `false`.

`true` is obviously truthy. `false` is obviously falsey. The rest can be a little tricky. MDN has possibly the clearest documentation about which values evaluate to falsey: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

In this case `[]` is a truthy value so the condition passes and the code is executed.